# SQL Declare Select Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert

I'm trying to get this query to run on all results of the select.
But the problem is the select from `LOG_ITEM201303` only returns one result.
So it means the `INSERT INTO` clause only affects one row each time I run this script.
But what I want to do is get all the results (600+ total) and insert all of them, row by row.

```
DECLARE @charkey int, @charname varchar(16), @item int

SELECT @charkey = CHAR_KEY, @charname = NAME, @item = ITEMNUM
FROM LOG_ITEM201303
where 
(   
    ITEMNUM = 14317
OR  ITEMNUM = 14318
OR  ITEMNUM = 15478
OR  ITEMNUM = 15479
OR  ITEMNUM = 14301
OR  ITEMNUM = 14302
OR  ITEMNUM = 15476
OR  ITEMNUM = 15477
OR  ITEMNUM = 15018
OR  ITEMNUM = 15019
OR  ITEMNUM = 15020
OR  ITEMNUM = 15021
OR  ITEMNUM = 15022
OR  ITEMNUM = 15023
OR  ITEMNUM = 15024
OR  ITEMNUM = 15025
OR  ITEMNUM = 14437
OR  ITEMNUM = 14438
OR  ITEMNUM = 15656
OR  ITEMNUM = 15657
OR  ITEMNUM = 15658
OR  ITEMNUM = 15659
OR  ITEMNUM = 15660
OR  ITEMNUM = 15661
OR  ITEMNUM = 15662
OR  ITEMNUM = 15663
) AND (KIND = 133) AND (Convert(varchar, OCCUR_TIME,111) < '2013/03/22')

SELECT @charkey, @charname, @item

INSERT INTO game.dbo.Mail_Item_Table
(ItemNumber, ItemInfo, ReceiveDate)
VALUES
(@item, (SELECT CONVERT(BINARY(16), REVERSE(CONVERT(BINARY(16), @item)))), NULL)

INSERT INTO game.dbo.Mail_Message_Table
(Message)
VALUES
('Automated Message from the ADMIN.')

INSERT INTO game.dbo.Mail_List_Table
(ReceiverCharKey, MailListIndex, MailItemIndex, MailMessageIndex, Sender, Receiver, SendDate)
VALUES 
(@charkey,
(SELECT TOP 1   MailListIndex+1 as last_entry
 FROM           game.dbo.Mail_List_Table
 WHERE          sender = 'SEND0R'
 ORDER BY MailListIndex DESC),
(SELECT TOP 1   MailItemIndex AS last_entry
 FROM           game.dbo.Mail_Item_Table
 ORDER BY       MailItemIndex DESC),
(SELECT TOP 1   MailMessageIndex AS last_entry
 FROM           game.dbo.Mail_Message_Table
 ORDER BY       MailMessageIndex DESC),
 'SEND0R', '@charname', getdate())
```

Comment: Actually NO, It's not a duplicate. :)

Comment: OK - the main issue is that you select into variables - that only ever works for a single row - since each variable can only hold a single value. What you need to do is insert into the target tables directly from the `SELECT`  - not using any variables in between... or if you need to use the same data to do multiple inserts, you'll need to store the results from the initial `SELECT` in a **table variable** (not individual variables for each row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that you select into individual variables - that only ever works for a single row - since each variable can only hold a single value. Also: with SQL in general, you should avoid the "row-by-row" (also known as ***RBAR*** - *row-by-agonizing-row*) approach - it's just a bad design, and kills off any performance you might get from set-based approaches. Avoid it whenever possible!

What you need to do instead is insert the data into the target tables directly from the `SELECT`  - not using any variables in between... or if you need to use the same data to do multiple inserts (as it looks like in your case here), you'll need to store the results from the initial `SELECT` in a **table variable** (not individual variables for each row)

So try something like this:

```
-- define a table variable to hold the data
DECLARE @TemporaryData TABLE (charkey int, charname varchar(16), item int)

-- initial SELECT - insert data into table variable    
INSERT INTO @TemporaryData(charkey, charname, item)
   SELECT CHAR_KEY, NAME, ITEMNUM
   FROM LOG_ITEM201303
   WHERE ( ..... ) 

-- insert data from the table variable into the first table    
INSERT INTO game.dbo.Mail_Item_Table(ItemNumber, ItemInfo, ReceiveDate)
   SELECT 
       item, 
       CONVERT(BINARY(16), REVERSE(CONVERT(BINARY(16), item)))), 
       NULL
   FROM @TemporaryData

-- unrelated to the table variable ...    
INSERT INTO game.dbo.Mail_Message_Table(Message)
VALUES('Automated Message from the ADMIN.')

-- insert data from table variable into yet another table...    
INSERT INTO game.dbo.Mail_List_Table(ReceiverCharKey, MailListIndex, MailItemIndex, MailMessageIndex, Sender, Receiver, SendDate)
  SELECT
      charkey,
     (SELECT TOP 1 MailListIndex+1 as last_entry
      FROM game.dbo.Mail_List_Table
      WHERE sender = 'SEND0R'
      ORDER BY MailListIndex DESC),
     (SELECT TOP 1 MailItemIndex AS last_entry
      FROM game.dbo.Mail_Item_Table
      ORDER BY MailItemIndex DESC),
     (SELECT TOP 1 MailMessageIndex AS last_entry
      FROM game.dbo.Mail_Message_Table
      ORDER BY MailMessageIndex DESC),
     'SEND0R', 
     charname, 
     getdate()
   FROM @TemporaryData
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I got it. Just one more issue I noticed. I'll try to work this out.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the last query. 
It should be entering MailItemIndex and MailListIndex incrementingly.
+1 for each entry. But when I checked the data it showed that if the query runned 3 times, it also increments by +3. Where it should only do so by 1. Like MailListIndex: 11,12,13,14,15. What happens is: 11,14,17... so on..

Comment: Seem's like its best I query this in loop.